# Difficulty in evaluating the constants of simultaneous equations

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra, symbolic

How to find the constants A1, A2, B1, B2 using linear solve or null space function in Mathematica.

```
ClearAll;
W1 = A1*Sin[b*x] + B1*Cos[b*x];
W2 = A2*Sin[b*(x - z)] + B2*Cos[b*(x - z)];
(*Boundary condition*)
e1 = W1 /. {x -> 0};
e2 = (D[W1, {x, 1}]) /. {x -> 1};
(*Compatability condition*)
e3 = (W1 /. {x -> z}) - (W2 /. {x -> z});
e4 = ((D[W1, {x}]) /. {x -> z}) - ((D[W2, {x}]) /. {x -> z});
(*Forming matrix*)

R = Normal@
   CoefficientArrays[{e1, e2, e3, e4}, {A1, B1, A2, B2}][[2]];
MatrixForm[R]
LinearSolve[R, {0, 0, 0, 1}]
NullSpace[R]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to solve your equations is:

```
e1 == W1 /. {x -> 0};
e2 == (D[W1, {x, 1}]) /. {x -> 1};
e3 = (W1 /. {x -> z}) - (W2 /. {x -> z});
e4 = ((D[W1, {x}]) /. {x -> z}) - ((D[W2, {x}]) /. {x -> z});
Solve[{e1, e2, e3, e4} == {0, 0, 0, 1}, {A1, A2, B1, B2}]
```

[image]

However, look at your equations:

```
TableForm[Transpose[Append[Transpose[R], {0, 0, 0, 1}]], 
 TableHeadings -> {{}, {"A1", "B1", "A2", "B2", "1"}}]
```

[image]

The first row states: B1==0, the second: A1==0, the third: B2==0 and the last: A2==-1/b. Is this really what you want or are the equations erroneous?